# "nvm use 10.14.0" caused "ng server" err

Tags: nvm-windows

Everything fine when `nvm use 8.14.0`, once `nvm use 10.14.0` or higher will get err. Windows 10, nvm 1.1.7

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to download the Angular CLI to the specific npm version?

For example: do the following:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: what version should be?

Comment: The above snippet of code with automatically install the latest version of the angular CLI.